# how to apply filters in jsf

Tags: jsf

I have a filter and I get Page not Found error when any client requests a JSF page in my  web application. I don't know how to fix this issue.

Here is my filter code:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
HttpSession ses = req.getSession(true);
String pageRequested = req.getRequestURL().toString();
if (ses.getAttribute("userDetails") != null) {
    fc.doFilter(request,response);      
} else {
    RequestDispatcher dis = request.getRequestDispatcher(LOGIN_PAGE);
    dis.forward(request,response);
}
```

I have done all the necessary settings in `web.xml` deployment descriptor.

Comment: what is the value of `LOGIN_PAGE`

Comment: public static LOGIN_PAGE="faces/login.jsp"

Answer (score 0):

A 404 simply means that the requested resource is not found. Down to the point this can have 2 causes:

1. The URL is invalid (i.e. `LOGIN_PAGE` is invalid).
2. The resource is not there where you think it is.

To further nail down the cause in this particular problem we need to know 2 things:

1. What is the absolute URL of the current request? Print `request.getRequestURL()`.
2. What is the absolute URL with which you can open the login page independently in webbrowser?

Then, you should be able to extract the correct `LOGIN_PAGE` from this information.

Comment: public static LOGIN_PAGE="faces/login.jsp"
Here this LOGIN_PAGE vaue This is correct only But why this 404 error occured

Comment: Because the relative URL is not correct. Once again, please mention absolute URL of the current request and the absolute URL of the login page itself.